# How to decrypt single file or folder?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, decryption

In the proces of encrypting the whole drive, an error occured and my drive was broken. I've managed to recover all files. However, some of them were still encrypted. I've tried using TrueCrypt, but there's no option to decrypt single files, just whole drive/partition.

Is there a way to encrypt/decrypt particular files?

Comment: What is wrong with creating a Truecrypt container then putting a single file in it?

Comment: I suspect nothing, except the OP apparently got stuck in the middle of encrypting the partition, so some files are encrypted on disk and others are not.

Comment: user5292408, welcome to Super User. Unfortunately product recommendation questions are off topic here. I recommend that you [edit] your question to focus on how to retrieve your data, rather than for people to recommend software. (As it stands, this question may very well be put on hold.) Also, when you edit, do make sure to answer the obvious question: do you have any recent backup? Because restoring from backup is almost certainly going to be vastly easier than any other method of recovery.

Comment: These are not very important data I want to retrieve, just some photos of which I have no backup. Fortunately I keep the more important data in cloud.